# Android developers fee without credit card?

Tags: android, publishing, credit-card, google-play

I've created an application for android, wich took me several months to complete. I've always been thinking that when it'd be done, I could publish it on Android market.
Now I went to the website, and found I had to pay €25, wich I was prepared to do. But then I found out that **I Cannot pay it without a credit card!**
Does anyone have a solution for this? I worked really too hard on my program to find it will never see daylight.

Comment: As far as I know, you must supply a credit card

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you want to pay? Send Google cash? And how did YOU expect to be paid by your customers?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is likely to be closed as it doesn't relate directly to programming. The only advice I would give is ask a friend / parent / teacher to pay with their credit card and you re-imburse them with cash.

Comment: well, there's iDeal, PayPal etc... Just a transfer through the bank. btw, i'm from holland.

Comment: Go to your local Walmart and get a pre-paid credit card :)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the official Android market there are many alternatives.
If you want to release your app on Android market, then there is no other way but using your credit card. If you don't care about the official market you can put your app on alternatives one such as:

- [www.androidpit.de](http://www.androidpit.de)
- [www.slideme.org](http://www.slideme.org)
- [www.handster.com](http://www.handster.com/)

Comment: Also good ones are AppBrain and AndroLib

Answer (score 3):

Theses pre-paid "credit cards" are available at gas stations throughout the US:

http://usa.visa.com/personal/cards/prepaid/index.html

Comment: Good point - we have some pre-paid cards available here in the UK too.

Comment: Do they have names or brands? since I haven't seen any of them in Holland..

Comment: @usealbarazer: The link Steve provides is for Visa, the cards we have here are Visa also. Just go to www.visa.com and select your country if your browser doesn't automatically detect it.

Comment: But how does one get paid using a prepaid card? I'm guessing we get paid on the credit card we supply... Barely did any research on this, just started looking.

Comment: In Germany there are cost-free banks where you can get such a prepaid-cc, usually authenticated by PostIden.